# Custom attributes in xaml resourcedictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a xaml resource dictionary as below

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                    xmlns:loc="http://temp/uri" 
                    mc:Ignorable="loc">
    <sys:String x:Key="ResouceKey" loc:Note="This is a note for the resource.">ResourceText</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am looping through all .xaml files in and trying to convert to POCO class and get the loc:Note attributes as well with using XamlReader.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(...))
{
    var xamlreader = new XamlReader();
    var resourceDictionary = xamlreader.LoadAsync(sr.BaseStream) as ResourceDictionary;
    if (resourceDictionary == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    foreach (var key in resourceDictionary.Keys)
    {
        // In this loop i would like to get the loc:Note
        var translation = new Translation
            {
                LocaleKey = locale, 
                Note = string.Empty, // How to get the note from the xaml
                Text = resourceDictionary[key] as string
            });
    }
}
```

Is this possible or do I have to resort to using custom xml serialization logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XamlReader` contains a Dictionary with key/value pair only. It will ignore custom attributes unless you create your own class or type. String is a primitive item and will be shown as such, not a class that may have other properties.

It would be cleaner and safer to just create a class:

```
public class MyString {
    public string _string { get; set; }
    public string _note { get; set; } 
}
```

And then store those in your ResourceDictionary. Now you can convert the value as so: `(MyString)r.Values[0]` and then assign them to your `Translation` object.

Comment: Hi, We are using these as the resource files for the wpf application so having the custom type might cause some inconveniences. I'm just trying to extract these to a custom localization engine which will then generate the xaml resources and mapping the actual localizations from the engine. However i might be able to adjust the source material xaml files as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. It makes more sense. In that case, if your file's structure is simple enough, parsing it as XML might be easiest route. Do you need code for that?

Comment: If you have it ready at hand that'd be great, thanks. But I think I can manage.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, ended up using xdoc to read the xaml resources. Seems to work.

Comment: This answered my question but solved the other way :)

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using Xdocument to read the xaml resources.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(...);
if (xdoc.Root != null)
{
    XNamespace xNs = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml";
    XNamespace sysNs = "clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib";
    XNamespace locNs = "http://temp/uri";

    foreach (var str in xdoc.Root.Elements(sysNs + "String"))
    {
        var keyAttribute = str.Attribute(xNs + "Key");
        if (keyAttribute == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        var noteAttribute = str.Attribute(locNs + "Note");

        var translation = new Translation
            {
                LocaleKey = locale,
                Note = noteAttribute != null ? noteAttribute.Value : null,
                Text = str.Value
            });
    }
}
```